# ASP.NET Core - How to resolve SmtpClient does not contain a definition for Connect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, mailkit, asp.net-core-7.0

In ASP.NET Core 7 Web API application I installed `NETCore.MailKit-2.1.0` package for e-mail notification.

Then I have this method:

```
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MimeKit;

private void Send(MimeMessage mailMessage)
{
    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            client.Connect(_emailConfig.SmtpHost, _emailConfig.SmtpPort, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.None);
            client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
            client.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;

            client.Send(mailMessage);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Information(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex));
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Disconnect(true);
            client.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

I got this error:

> SmtpClient does not contain a definition for Connect and no accessible extension method connect

Then connect is highlighted in `client.Connect`.

The same thing happens to `client.AuthenticationMechanisms`, `client.CheckCertificateRevocation` and `client.Dispose()`.

I downgraded to NETCore.MailKit-2.0.3, but the error still remains.

How do I get this resolved?

Comment: SmptClient is part of MailKit, not `NETCore.MailKit`. The package you used is an unfortunately-named extension that registers an `IEmailService` wrapper over Mailkit so you don't have to create an SmptClient explicitly

Comment: What's the *full* error? What is `_emailConfig.SmtpPort`? Does the error complain there's no `Connect` that accepts a string for the port? The only [Connect overload](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Overload_MailKit_Net_Smtp_SmtpClient_Connect.htm) that matches your code expects `host` to be a string and `port` to be an int

Comment: You can refer to this [Tutorial](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2022/03/11/net-6-send-an-email-via-smtp-with-mailkit) about Sending an Email via SMTP with MailKit.

Answer (score 0):

step 1- add Install-Package MailKit from Nuget Console
step 2- Rerence using MailKit.Net.Smtp;

Comment: This should be a comment at best. The comments posted 3 months ago do a better job of explaining what's wrong - the wrong NuGet package was used.